# UIImageView has weird space to the left of the image in a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a `UITableView` that I programatically add to my view. I then load the data from an API, and resize the images to fit it to the width of the current device, and accordingly adjust the height of the image to keep the aspect ration, I then use that height as the height of the cells for my table view.

Here is some code and a screenshot of the result:

This is the image resize code:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image convertToWidth:(float)width {
    float ratio = image.size.width / width;
    float height = image.size.height / ratio;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage * newimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newimage;
}
```

This is in the init method of my custom table view cell:

```
 _imgPicture = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
 _imgPicture.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
 [self.contentView addSubview:_imgPicture];
```

This is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
RecipeTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"recipe_cell"];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[RecipeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"recipe_cell"];
}
NSDictionary *dict = [recipeArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.lblName.text = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];

if([@"data:image/jpg;base64,null" isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",[dict valueForKey:@"pictureType"], [dict valueForKey:@"picture"]]])
{
    cell.imgPicture.image = defaultImage;
}
else
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",[dict valueForKey:@"pictureType"], [dict valueForKey:@"picture"]]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    cell.imageView.image = [ImageExtension imageWithImage:ret convertToWidth:screenWidth];
}

return cell;
```

[image: Screen shot of the resulting view]

I have tried forcing the `UIImageView` to be at origin 0, 0 by settings the frame, but that didn't help, I am now thinking that it might be the fact that the image gets resized, and then something in the `UITableViewCell` breaks, but have no idea what it could be. Some assistance with this will be much appreciated.

Also note I had all this as a storyboard, and it had the exact same result, then I thought let me attempt it programatically and getting the same results.

Comment: add UIImageView in cell and don't use cell default imageview... that will solve the problem...

Comment: @FahimParkar I am not using the default image view

Comment: @FahimParkar Ok so I rechecked and as you said, I was using the wrong imageview, thanks dude

Comment: I posted an answer... mark it accepted if its right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
cell.imageView.image
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

to

```
cell.imgPicture.image
     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will solve problem...

Answer (score 0):

first u can ensure resizing of image by giving tableview any backgroundcolor
secondly, if using ios8 then see your constraits
thirdly, if any ios then check indentation of uitableviewcell

Comment: Any idea which constraints to check, it is all build programatically, I have added a background color to the cell and the cell fills the entire width as expected. I added `cell.indentationLevel = 0;` and also `cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, screenWidth, [cell.imageView.image size].height);` I also tried removing the constraints from the content view of the cell